# mapping props is undefined when passed into component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that loops around a collection of objects. I have also attempted to write the component using a stateless function. My set up is as followed:

**app.jsx**

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Table';
import Headings from './intro/headings';
const headings = ['Last change at', 'By Author', 'Summary'];

class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const rows = this.props.data.map((row, i) =>
      <Row row={row} key={i} />
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
          <Headings headings={this.props.headings} />
          <tbody>
            {rows}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Welcome.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
  headings: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Welcome
    name={newPerson}
    title="Recent Changes"
    headings={headings}
    data={data}
  />,
  document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

**headings.jsx**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Heading from './heading';

const Headings = this.props.map((name, i) =>
  <Heading heading={name} key={i} />
);

Headings.propTypes = {
  heading: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Headings;
```

My app seems to compile fine, however when I open it in the browser I keep getting: `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined(…)` in chromes web console. I'm very new to React and am feeling my way around a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement:

```
const Headings = this.props.map((name, i) =>
  <Heading heading={name} key={i} />
);
```

`this` refers to module context and has no `props` property. It only makes sense to invoke `this.props` inside of a component.

This should work:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Heading from './heading';

const Headings = props => (
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {
        props.headings.map((name, i) =>
          <Heading heading={name} key={i} />
        )
      }
    </tr>
 </thead>
)

export default Headings;
```

Comment: Thanks, with that said I'm now getting: `A valid React element (or null) must be returned`. If i understand correctly the issue here is that I am not returning a valid react element. However if i define a simple function such as the following this will work.  `const Headings = function () {
  return <div>Test</div>;
};` Essentially all i am trying to do is write a stateless function that returns a react element.

Comment: Also edited my question which includes a workaround.

Comment: I see the change that was made, so the contents of the `<thead>...</thead>` have been wrapped inside the first function.